# A decomposable element in the tensor product $V \otimes W$

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products, tensors, tensor-decomposition

In the book of *A Course in Algebra* by E. B. Vinberg, at page $298$, it is given that,

> An element $z \in V \otimes W$, i.e in the tensor product of the space
>   $V$ and $W$, is called decomposable if it decomposes as $$z = x
>  \otimes y \quad x\in V, y \in W$$

However, since $z \in V \otimes W$, by definition it has to be written as 
$$z = x \otimes y.$$

I mean is there any change it cannot be written in this form ? So I didn't get it what is special about decomposability of $z$.

Comment: Some tensors cannot simply be written as tensor products. Take the linear combination of two decomposable tensors, for instance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $V=W$ be two dimensional, with basis $\{e,f\}$. Consider
$$e\otimes e+f\otimes f.$$